# How to add dotted line after text?

Tags: css

I need a dotted line after the text. The dotted line should be till the end of the line. In the example below, after Organisation/Agency text, dotted line should start and should last till the end of the line. With
the code below, I am getting the dotted line below the text as well which is not what I want.

```
Organisation/Agency.................................................
```

I tried as below.

```css
.horizontal_dotted_line {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal_dotted_line">
  Organisation/Agency
</div>
```

But the output I am getting is

```
Organisation/Agency
.................................................
```

My required output is
Organisation/Agency........................................

Answer (score 10):

You can use `:after` pseudo-element for dotted line and also set `display: flex` on parent element. With `flex: 1` on pseudo element it will take rest of free width.

```css
.horizontal_dotted_line {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
} 
.horizontal_dotted_line:after {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal_dotted_line">Organisation/Agency</div>
<div class="horizontal_dotted_line">Lorem</div>
```

Comment: In this case, the `flex: 1;` shorthand is only really using is `flex-grow: 1;`, so to keep it more readable and explicit, I'd suggest using that. I also used a `margin-left: 5px;` within the `:after` to give it some spacing. Lastly, if you want to center-align the dots, use `align-items: center;` in the primary selector

Answer (score 7):

```css
.horizontal_dotted_line{
     width: 200px;
     display : flex;
    } 
    .dot{
      flex: 1;
      border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
      height: 0.6em;
    }
```

```html
<div class="horizontal_dotted_line">Organisation/Agency<span class="dot"></span></div>
```

Comment: I have got a dotted line underneath the text with your code, I just need the dotted line after the text. Organisation/Agency.................................................

Comment: @ChinnaR  adjust height as per your requirement , and remove `width: 200px;` if you want full width , otherwise depends on your `width`

Comment: Remove: "width: 200px;" from horizontal_dotted_line and add "width: 100%;" to .dot , it will work well; Thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple. A pseudo :after element.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
}

div:after {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Organisation/Agency
</div>
```

Comment: This has effected all the divs on the page.

Comment: @ChinnaR Use flex layout. See the updated code. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best method, try to this.

```css
.horizontal_dotted_line {
    position: relative;
}
.horizontal_dotted_line span {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.horizontal_dotted_line:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    border-top: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal_dotted_line">
  <span>Organisation/Agency</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Organisation/Agency text is striked out with dotted line